# Json.Net Is it faster to deserialize to JObject or Dictionary?

Tags: c#, performance, json.net

I'm trying to model a Json for deserialization where one of the properties is an object with a long list of keys and values.

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",

    //this guy
    "longlist": {
        "6060": 123,
        "6061": 664,
...
        "6200": 43
    }
}
```

In my application, I don't need to look inside `longlist`, I only want to be able to append one `longlist` to another.

Is it better for me to model `longlist` as a `Dictionary<string, int>` or as a `JObject`, considering the performance of deserialization for each?

edit: order of keys in `longlist` doesn't matter.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance until it becomes an issue in your application to be honest

Comment: You can time both approaches yourself if you're really interested in finding out. It's likely dependent on the data, so testing it yourself is going to give you the best answer.

Comment: Related advice from Eric Lippert: [*If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses**.*](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I have no idea which will be faster, you just need to measure it yourself.  However, `Dictionary<string, int>` will have a smaller memory footprint because the `int` values will not get boxed, and because it is only single-keyed (by name) rather than double-keyed ([by name and document order](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JPropertyKeyedCollection.cs)).

Comment: I'm actually more interested in **why** one model might be more performant than another (like @dbc's answer), and learning something that way.   
Also if someone already knows that one way is *definitely* the better way to do this, why should I spend time measuring the two?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> longlist { get; set; }
}
```

JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(r);

```
JObject objResponse = (JObject)jsonResponse["longlist"];
RootObject _Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse.ToString());

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in _Data.longlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0} Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
}
```

fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ZyKwN

Comment: deserialize into JObject or Dictionary that's not more time consumable.